# Move left or right to fast causes img to stick

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a spaceship invaders game in python 3 with pygame. I am currently having troubles with the spaceship sticking making me  double tap a left or right arrow key for it to take effect. Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

#Window Size
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
#Title Of Window
pygame.display.set_caption('A Bit Racey')
#FPS
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

spaceshipImg = pygame.image.load('SpaceShipSmall.png')

def spaceship(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(spaceshipImg, (x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

x_change  = 0

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    # this will listen for any event every fps
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #change later
            crashed = True

        if event.type  == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    spaceship(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every time a `pygame.KEYUP` event is detected** for the left or right arrow key you **reset `x_change`**. Even when you *hold down* e.g. your right arrow key **a single** left arrow **key press stops the movement** of your spaceship.

To solve this problem you could **use the [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) method to get the state of all keyboard buttons**. **This function returns a sequence of boolean values** indexed by *pygames key constant values* representing the state of every key on the keyboard.

Because **you don´t need to call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` every time an event happens**, the updated main loop should look like this:

```
while not crashed:
    # this will listen for any event every fps
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #change later
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    #get the state of all keyboard buttons
    pressedKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #change position if pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT is pressed
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x += -5
    elif pressedKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 5

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    spaceship(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

**Notice** that a `pygame.K_LEFT` event has a *higher priority* than a `pygame.K_RIGHT` event. You could change this behavior by using **two separate `if` blocks**. *Many thanks to **@sloth** for pointing this out!*:

```
#change position if either pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT is pressed
if pressedKeys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x += -5
if pressedKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    x += 5
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Instead of adding the `if pressedKeys[pygame.K_LEFT] and pressedKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:    pass ... `-part you could simple change the `elif` to `if`.

Comment: @sloth: Oh yah :) You are clever! :D Thank you very much. I will change my answer...

Answer (score 0):

add the following statement before x += x_change:

```
print (event.type, event.key, x)
```

this will print the event data and x position to the console.

try your script again, try holding down the left key for 3 seconds, then release, and repeat for the right key. See if you see multiple keydown events while holding down the keys. I think you should only see one keyup event upon release.